# Can't connect to localhost on port 8443 for tomcat https

Tags: tomcat, https, tomcat7, keystore

I've installed tomcat and it is running perfectly fine.

However, I can't access it via https layer.

Port 8080 works fine:

```
curl -IL http://localhost:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sat, 27 Apr 2013 16:20:23 GMT
```

Port 8443 doesn't respond:

```
curl -IL https://localhost:8443
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

This line is uncommented in my server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
 maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
 sslProtocol="TLS"
 keystoreFile="/usr/me/.keystore" 
 keystorePass="somepwd" />
```

I've even changed the protocol to `"org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"` but that hasn't helped either.

I have restarted the tomcat service after every change but yet:

```
curl https://localhost:8443
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

My tomcat version is 7.0.39

I've generated my `.keystore` file with this command `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA`

Answer (score 1):

Changed you settings like below and it should work

```
  <!-- SSL Port 8443 --> 
  <Connector port="8443" 
  maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" 
  SSLEngine="on" 
  SSLCertificateFile="mycert.crt" 
  SSLCertificateKeyFile="mykey.pem" 
  SSLPassword="....." 
  clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Comment: how are you generating the `.crt` and `.pem` files. I only have a `.keystore` file